# Age, gender, & country not showing in Facebook Insights data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

Nearly all the other metrics are available to view in Facebook Insights, except the user demographics. When I try to view them, I get an empty array:

```
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "page_impressions_by_age_gender_unique",
         "period": "day",
         "values": [
            {
               "value": {

               },
               "end_time": "2015-10-08T07:00:00+0000"
            }
         ],
         "title": "Daily Reach Demographics",
         "description": "Daily: Total Page Reach by age and gender.",
         "id": "x/insights/page_impressions_by_age_gender_unique/day"
      }
   ],
```

I have most permissions set: read_insights, manage_pages, publish_actions.

Comment: Checking  for a page I admin, I see no data for the day period for most of the days over the last couple weeks (with 2015-09-19 being the exception, that shows some data.) Periods week and days_28 however show accumulated data. I’d suggest you go check if there’s any open bug reports for that, and if not file one.

Comment: Hello, did you find out an explanation  to this ?

Comment: @Catalin Yes, if I remember right I didn't have enough people liking to page to display the gender results. I think I had to get it up to 30? 40?

Comment: For page fans there is the following metric: page_fans_gender_age, which indeed you need at least 30 likes. But the page_impressions_by_age_gender_unique should give you information about users who viewed your page on a specific day, so I m not sure how is the last metric related with the 'number of likes' requirement.

Comment: Also although my page has 30 likes, when I query for  page_impressions_by_age_gender_unique sometimes I get results, but for other timeRange(since-until) I get nothing and I m sure that I have at least 10 impressions per day. I'm thinking that it might be a fb requirement which says that  in order to get page_impressions_by_age_gender_unique i need to have at least x number of unique viewers per day... (i assume)

Answer (score 0):

For me it's working for my page. If you don't have for daily means search in weekly or 28 days report. May be todays report not updated yet.

"Daily Reach Demographics" Also have "weekly and 28_days Reach Demographics" Search for that. And "read_insights" permission will be okay for this action.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is related to one of these Facebook issues:

- [1993653884193030](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1993653884193030/): page_impressions_by_age_gender_unique missing from page insights
- [1010193999087765](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1010193999087765/): Some metrics are missing for period "day"

Response from Facebook:

> This is actually not a bug, but by design. There are not enough impressions/data available to create a breakdown for that specific timeframe (in your case "day") so we do not return any data.